# binary files update in C++

Tags: c++, file, binary

I'm new to binary files,
My binary file is written in a length indicator way and I want to know if there is a way I can update it (writing to it) without overwriting it (shifting the text)?
And how deleting can be done (deleting with shifting backwards)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't to that. If you want to delete a piece of data in your file, you will need to re-write the remainder of the file.

pseudo-code:

```
- Open original file for read
- Open temp file for write
- While data in original file
    - If original file data is needed
        - Write data to temp file
- Delete original file
- Rename temp file to original file name
```

Comment: You mean into another temp file?

Comment: Yeah. You write to a temp file then you rename the temp file to the name of your original file.